# JPQL distinct with string function

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have a JPQL like this one:

```
select distinct d 
from Department d
left join fetch d.employees
```

When I want to fetch one of the lazy property of my Department entity, the **distinct is not working any more**.

```
select distinct d, substring(d.htmlDescription, 1,400)
from Department d
left join fetch d.employees
```

The query returns as much Department as the number of employees in it.

The `substring(d.htmlDescription)` is important because the property is defined as a CLOB (type TEXT under postgresql):

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
String htmlBody;
```

The substring function is translated in sql thus limiting the amount of data transfered beetween the database and the web server.

As a workaround, I tried to break the query in two parts :

```
select d, substring(d.htmlDescription, 1,400)
from Department d where d in (
    select distinct d1
    from Department d1  left join fetch d1.employees
)
```

This doestn't work because the `JOIN FETCH` must not be used in the `FROM` clause of a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem by :

1. modifying my mapping
2. cutting the request in 2 calls.

The htmlBody field is now in another entity. Thus the departement entity is lighter.

```
class Department{
...
@OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
    cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
Content content = new Content();
...
}


class Content{
...
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
String htmlBody;
...
}
```

I can then use the following requests :

```
    List<Department> deps = em.get().createQuery(
            "select distinct d " +
                    "from Department d " +
                    "order by d.id desc ", Department.class)
            .setFirstResult(first)
            .setMaxResults(count)
            .getResultList();

    List<Object[]> tuple = em.get().createQuery(
            "select d, substring(d.content.htmlBody, 1,400)" +
                    "from Department d " +
                    "left join fetch d.employees" +
                    "where d in (:deps) order by d.id desc")
            .setParameter("deps", deps)
            .getResultList();

    ... //Filter the duplicates due to the fetching
```

That way, I have 2 sql queries. The fetching of employees is done in the second query witch occurs on a small amount of datas. The substring is realized in SQL. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot make comments, I would like to point out few things that stick out to me as doubtfull.

1. What is the object returned with `distinct d, substring(d.htmlDescription, 1,400)`? Could you fetch that String with separate query, or get that substing using Java?
2. I would trust that that query can be rewritten into one without left join statement.
3. Maybe you could rewrite the query so you could put substring statement first and then distinct d?

Comment: 1. I added the reason of using the substring jpql function instead of java.

Comment: 2. The left join is used for the fetch. It is the only lazy relation that I want to load on that query. Without the fetch the result is a N+1 selects.

Comment: 3. I don't understand your proposal.